# How to convert a deeply nested part of json into a single string with Go

Tags: json, go, encoding-json-go

I have some json data that has a structure similar to the following:

```
{
     "value1": "some value"
     "value2": "some other value"
     "value3": "another value"
     "value4": {
          "data":[
              {
                ...more nested values here with a few more levels
               }
             ]
            }
}
```

How would I lay out the struct so that all the data for "value4" comes back as a single string with Go?

Currently I'm using json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(dataValues) where dataValues is a struct similar to:

```
type DataValues struct {
Value1 string `json:"value1"`
Value2 string `json:"value2"`
Value3 string `json:"value3"`
// not sure how to define Value4
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I lay out the struct so that all the data for "value4" comes back as a single string with Go?

If you want you can "delay" the unmarshaling and capture the part that you want to treat as a string by using [RawMessage](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) from `encoding/json`.

Here is a simple [solution](https://play.golang.org/p/o_RnGqxmPMd).